# Why do we need to declare enum variables? (C)

Tags: c, enums

I am starting to learn C language for the very first time. 
This question might sound pretty basic, but i will appreciate any help!

my question is, if you could simply do

```
enum day {
    mon, tue, wed
};

int main() {
    int today = mon; 
    return 0;
}
```

to set "today" variable as 0, why do most tutorial write like

```
enum day {
    mon, tue, wed
}today;

int main() {
    today = mon; 
    return 0;
}
```

I am seeing enum as something like a class. So it doesn't make sense to me to specify the variable that uses the enum. Why does the second way of writing more common?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumerations were added to the C language late. As a consequence, they are not “strongly typed”—C does not do much to distinguish them from other integer values—and so they are largely a convenience.

In theory, you can declare an object to be a enumeration type to indicate it should hold some value from the enumeration and not any other. The C standard does not require this be enforced. Some compilers may warn about violations of this in some circumstances, but they cannot catch them all.

Every identifier in an enumeration has an `int` value. Because of this, people use them as a way to define compile-time constants. Often these are simple consecutive constants, as for number the days of the week, but they may also be arbitrary constants such as bit masks or memory addresses (within the `int` range). That is not their true purpose, but it is something they are useful for, so people use it.

An enumeration type and any objects defined for it, such as something you declare `enum day today`, must have a type compatible with some integer type. For example, if all of the values in the enumeration are within the range of `char`, the enumeration type could be, effectively, `char`. This means it might take less space in a structure than declaring an `int`. However, the C standard does not mandate that compiler use the smallest integer type that fits, so this feature is not useful for relying on enumerations to limit the space used.

The C standard also does not require any warnings when some general integer value is assigned to an enumeration object. With the existing design of enumerations this is not really possible—since enumeration identifiers are `int` values, the right-hand side of any assignment that uses them, as in `today = Monday + 1`, is an `int` at least, not clearly a value in the enumeration, and it becomes hard for a compiler to diagnose problems.

Because of these lax rules about enumerations, there is no hard-and-fast rule about defining objects to be enumeration types rather than, say, `int` or `char`. One might wish to define something to be an enumeration type to convey to future readers of the source code that it is being used to record things in that enumeration type, but one also might wish to define it to be a `uint8_t` to ensure it uses only one byte in an array or structure. So there are conflicting reasons for the choices, and an author is going to have to choose one or another.

In general, if you are simply using an enumeration in code to hold and work with the enumeration values, and it is not part of an array or structure or other thing where space matters much, then define it using the enumeration type. This best conveys to the reader, and the compiler, your intent for it.

Answer (score -1):

enums are in the fact integers. They are used for code type correctness, better readability, better error messaging (modern compilers may even warn you if not all enums were used in the switch ... case) and more convenient debugging.

Comment: Enumerations do little or nothing for code type correctness. Per C 2018 6.7.2.2, the type of an enumeration constant is `int`, and each enumerated type must be compatible with `char` or some signed or unsigned integer type, thus making it essentially indistinguishable from that type within the rules of the C standard. So any compiler assistance in diagnosing misuse of enumerations is grafted on.